# what happen to jquery animation queue promise when stop is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, promise

I was wondering about what happen to an animation queue promise state when the .stop() function is called on it.

For example:

```
$('.my-elem')
    .stop(true, true)
    .animate({})
    .promise()
    .always(function() {
        // do something
    })
```

If the `.stop()` function get called at any point, what happen to the promise returned earlier ?

Right now, I get the feeling the promise returned just keep on pending forever. Any clue on this ?

Comment: Why are you basing this "on feelings"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stopping the animation resolves the promise.

```
//start the anim and alert 'done' on deferred resolution
$('div').animate({height: 500}, 3000).promise().done(function() {
    alert('deferred resolved');
});

//interrupt it after 1 second
setTimeout(function() { $('div').stop(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: And is there a way to know if the animation have completed or if it has been stopped ?